Issue with USB Tethering/Ethernet after installint some basic updates in Ubuntu 22.04.5
Yesterday I installed a bunch of system updates I had been putting off for a while, and after I did so I had issues connecting to USB Tethering (The only way I can access internet on my computer), yesterday I managed to fix the issue when I just turned it off and back on, although it ran significantly slower than usual. Today however, it just won't work whatsoever. It says that it is connected properly, but everything that requires the internet refuses to function, saying no internet is connected.

does it make a new interface when you connect the usb ?
maybe you should check the ip route, ip address ... and some tools like ping,traceroute may help you to gather some useful info

I dont think so? How dan I check the ip route?

type sudo ip r

What do i need to look for in the ip route? And Ping doesn't work, says "Temporary failure in name resolutipn" regardless of what I ping, and I dont have traceroute installed

look for default route this would be the gateway through the internet. check your NIC to get ip and check your dns too

Can you explain it to me like im an idiot? Cause I am
